# Can we determine if the data pointed was allocated manually or not?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

The question is pretty much that. In C++, if a pointer is not `NULL` is there any way to determine if the data pointed was allocated on the heap (`new`-type allocation) or on the stack (typical allocation and current scope lifetime).

I have an implementation of smart pointers and arrays (I know smart pointers exist in C++11 but I avoid them until there's a cleaner way to add smart arrays than currently) in which I keep track of reference count and so on. Whenever a pointer is not referenced at all anymore it is delete. Problem is, the current implementation doesn't prevent to give to the class a pointer to a variable on the stack (I do not want to force the creation of the pointer by the smart pointer, I have specific case where I want to do the allocation myself, for example when creating an array in a function and in the same function it needs a resize before being handed to the caller and so on), but if I give such a pointer, the class will try to call a `delete` or a `delete[]` on this pointer, which will result in undefined behavior (well let's be honest, a crash in most cases).

So is there a way that I check if I should or not delete this pointer on destruction or if the class should even accept it in the first place ?

Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: No general/portable solution for detecting this. I did not get why you're not using standard smart pointers...

Comment: Well standard C++11 smart pointers do not have a direct array equivalent, you need to provide a customized deleter (don't remember how to do this since the solution was not too elegant). Since the algorithm is very basic and far from CPU intensive I stick with my implementation for now ;) Thanks for the info by the way !

Comment: @DevilBlackDeath C++11 has `std::array` and `std::vector` depending on whether you need stack or heap allocation.

Comment: @MarkB But std::vector doesn't allow me to manage the lifetime of the allocation the same way a smart array does, which is why I use both ;) For a heap allocation that needs to be freed when exiting the current scope I use a std::vector but for a more granular lifetime I will use smart arrays (that's the case when I manage my SFML textures for example ;) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The best you could hope for is a non-portable hack based on some particular library's implementation details, and even that would have a non-zero false-positive results.

Comment: Well too bad :( At least this produces a rather understandable error at run-time when you're familiar with pointers, and since I don't intend to let anyone unfamiliar with C++ touch my code my current implementation should do the trick :)